# How to set bash as default shell?

Tags: cyanogenmod, bash

When I adb into a device with Cyanogenmod, I'm presented with a nice bash shell, color prompt, and bashrc.  I don't see a symlink from /system/xbin/bash to /system/bin/sh.  How do they set the default shell to bash instead of sh?  I looked through rc files, but didn't find anything.  I'd like to do the same on my Android build, which isn't Cyanogenmod.

**Update**

After re-installing from scratch with CM7, I'm taken to sh instead of bash.  Now the question is how to set bash as default.

Comment: Vanilla CM7 (built from source) drops me at `sh`, not `bash`, when I use adb to connect. What build are you using?

Comment: It's 7.1.0.1 for the ViewSonic G Tablet.  I didn't build from sources though.

Answer (score 8):

When `adb shell` is executed, the Android side also launches adb which then executes `/system/bin/sh -`. This path is hard-coded in `system/core/adb/services.c`:

```
347 #if ADB_HOST
348 #define SHELL_COMMAND "/bin/sh"
349 #define ALTERNATE_SHELL_COMMAND ""
350 #else
351 #define SHELL_COMMAND "/system/bin/sh"
352 #define ALTERNATE_SHELL_COMMAND "/sbin/sh"
353 #endif
```

If you want to change this to bash, you will have to recompile it.

It is possible to execute some commands from file when running the interactive shell. As written in `system/core/sh/main.c`, `sh -` (note the `-` for interactive mode) reads from the following files (in this order):

- `/etc/profile`
- `.profile` (relative to current directory, this is `/.profile` for `adb shell`
- `$ENV` (environment variable `ENV` should point to a file)

As `/etc/` and `/` are read-only, the only way to get something loaded was by setting `ENV`. You can probably create a symlink from `/etc/profile` to `/data/profile` by mounting `/` read-write (exercise for the reader).

Comment: /etc is a symlink to the /system partition. I remounted that read-write and added /etc/profile but it does not get called by sh :(

Answer (score 4):

I didn't have my Android with me right now to test, but with the [Android Terminal Emulator](https://market.android.com/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) if you go to the menu, you might be able to use the "Command line" or "Initial command" option.

[image]

Comment: Gee, I'll have to try that menu from my adb prompt.

Comment: Nothing related to OP question and `adb`

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but I was recently curious about this myself. I found a method that doesn't require recompiling `adbd`, however it does require `su` (I'm using Chainfire SuperSu 2.45).

Assuming `bash` is located at `/system/bin/bash`, and `su` is at `/system/xbin/su`, it's essentially something like this:

1. `adb shell` (use an interactive shell. Invoking this process as a
   one-liner could cause ADB to cease working if there is a problem)
2. `mount -o remount,rw /system`
3. `mv /system/bin/sh /system/bin/sh.bak`
4. `echo -e '#!/system/bin/bash\n/system/xbin/su -mm -l -s /system/xbin/bash' > /system/bin/sh`  Note that your paths may differ; use `which bash` and `which su` to be sure.
5. `chmod 777 /system/bin/sh`
6. Test the shell before you exit: `/system/bin/sh`.  If you get an error, fix the error or revert by restoring the backup: `cp /system/bin/sh.bak /system/bin/sh`.
7. Optionally remount /system; most devices will do this automatically: 
   `mount -o remount,ro /system`

And you're done.

Simply symlinking BASH to SH doesn't work because bash emulates SH when invoked this way.

However, having a look at strace, it does seem to look for a `bashrc` when a symlinked BASH is called as 'sh --login'. While this could conceivably be used to "chainload" shells via script, as mentioned above the way `adbd` invokes SH is hardcoded.

If there is a problem and you have removed (or moved) `/system/bin/sh` ADB wont have a shell to give you to fix the problem. If this happens, you have a few options:

- Reboot into a recovery that has `adbd` (such as CWM or TWRP) and open an adb shell to it, to copy /system/bin/sh.bak over to /system/bin/sh again.
- Use adb to copy the backup:  `adb root; adb remount; adb shell; adb pull /system/bin/sh.bak; adb push sh.bak /system/bin/sh`  Note that this won't work on all devices; some refuse to allow adb to remount /system rw in this way.
- Use a terminal emulator that can be set to run a different shell; note that several will try /system/bin/sh first and force close.

Answer (score 0):

On your PC, get a bash binary and overwrite `/system/bin/sh`.
I have one [here](https://github.com/SuperDethByte/Bash-for-ARM).

Feel free to copy this code:

```
git clone https://github.com/SuperDethByte/Bash-for-ARM.git        
cd Bash-for-ARM                
echo "Make sure your phone is plugged into your computer."          
sleep 5s                
echo "Remounting /system partition as r/w..."       
adb shell mount -o remount,rw /system          
echo "Making A Backup..."              
adb shell cp /system/bin/sh /system/bin/sh.bak         
echo "checking if backup was made..."          
if [ adb shell 'ls /system/bin/ | grep "sh.bak"' ]; then     
echo "pushing bash binary to android..."          
adb push bash /system/bin/sh       
echo "Remounting /system partition as r/o..."         
adb shell mount -o remount,ro /system          
echo "DONE"        
else         
echo "Backup Failed"           
echo "Remounting /system partition as r/o..."      
adb shell mount -o remount,ro /system     
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the proper & simple way from a Linux box, even in 2021 and [lineageos](/questions/tagged/lineageos):

```
adb shell -t bash -i
```

You logon directly via [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) in interactive way.

To not having to remember this command all the times, I personally
use an alias, simply add this to your `~/.bashrc` on Linux box:

```
alias adb_shell='adb shell -t bash -i'
source ~/.bashrc
```

Then all is configured, simply run

```
adb_shell
```

and enjoy all `bash` features like tab completion and anything. \o/