# Install Bash on rooted Kindle Fire

Tags: amazon-kindle-fire, shell, bash

I just rooted my Kindle Fire and installed QuickSSHd, an SSH daemon app.

I can log in via SSH (using Putty in Windows 7) and become root, etc. It appears, however, that the only shell installed is `sh` which lacks many of the niceties of other shells like Bash.

So, is it possible to install Bash (or a Bash-like shell with more features than `sh`) on a Kindle Fire?

Comment: Looks like [CM has bash](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19315/how-to-set-bash-as-default-shell), so you could flash it :P or maybe grab the binary and try it.

Comment: Is the /system filesystem writable (or can you remount it to that effect)? `mksh` works natively on Android. You can probably even just copy a binary over. Disclaimer: I’m the [`mksh`](https://www.mirbsd.org/mksh.htm) maintainer.