# Is there a workaround to use of bash via adb on LineageOS17?

Tags: adb, shell, bash

I try to login in my device directly vith

```
adb shell bash -i
```

It kind of partially works, because I'm logged with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), but the terminal loose completion.

The error I get:

```
$ adb shell bash -i 
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Not a typewriter
bash: no job control in this shell
mydevice / #
```

Is there something possible to do it properly without errors ? I don't have `su` installed.

Comment: do you mean `bash -l` because `bash -i` doesn't make sense to me without any cmd

Comment: -i stands for interactive, that's the wanted behavior

Comment: ... and -l is for login shell. are you saying bash without -i is not interactive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is expected. `adb shell` by default doesn't allocate a TTY (terminal) which is required for interactive session. Instead use:

```
adb shell -t bash -i
```

Comment: Found myself before: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/232537/20417 but thanks, that's the way I use